# como transformar dos listas en una lista de tuplas en haskell

Tags: haskell

tengo esta lista `["A","B","C","D"]` y esta otra `[["B","C"],["A","C"],["A","B","D"],["C"]]` y quiero convertirla a esto `[("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","A"),("B","C"),("C","A"),("C","B"),("C","D"),("D","C")]` por cada elemento de la primera lista crea una tupla con el primer elemento de la segunda lista es decir "A" con ["B","C"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución más sencilla:

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [(a,a)]
f xs ys = [(x,y) | (x,zs) <- zip xs ys, y <- zs]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f2 :: a -> [a] ->[(a,a)]
f2 a [] = []
f2 a (h:t) = (a,h):(f2 a t)

f :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [(a,a)]
f [] [] = []
f (h1:t1) (h2:t2) = (f2 h1 h2) ++ (f t1 t2)
```

Esta es una solución básica, que no contempla por ejemplo que las listas sean de diferentes tamaños, pero debería servirte para orientarte y mejorarla.